# How to determine BGA land pad diameter for given ball diameter?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, surface-mount, bga

I'm working on a project which requires the use of a CSP package. The product's datasheet provides ball pitch in each axis as X:710um Y:580um and ball diameter as 250um but nothing about the preferred land pad diameter.

How can the pad diameter be worked out from these figures assuming an NSMD land?

Comment: This might help you: http://blogs.mentor.com/tom-hausherr/blog/2011/01/08/pcb-design-perfection-starts-in-the-cad-library-part-9-bga-components/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well a good place to start for questions like these would be the IPC spec [PC-7351B](http://landpatterns.ipc.org/default.asp) not free but it has all the information you'd need about land patterns for most any part.

Second I like to use the free version of the [pcblibraries](http://www.pcblibraries.com/) tool because it automatically generates IPC compliant footprints from your input data, and can then output or create them in your CAD program.

Finally here's a link from [mentor](http://blogs.mentor.com/tom-hausherr/blog/2011/01/08/pcb-design-perfection-starts-in-the-cad-library-part-9-bga-components/) describing more than you'd ever want to know about BGA pad size.   For instance it shows this IPC table:

[image]

With your ball diameter being 0.25mm, that looks like a land pattern of 0.20mm.

Comment: You mean 0.25 and 0.2